# Solving for matrix X (using the Moore-Penrose Pseudoinverse)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-rank, pseudoinverse

Consider the following matrix equation:

$\mathbf{B'XB=A}$

where

- $\mathbf{X}$ is $m \times m$
- $\mathbf{B}$ is $m \times n$
- $\mathbf{A}$ is $n \times n$
- $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are known
- $\mathbf{X}$ is unknown
- $m>n$

I want to solve for $\mathbf{X}$. This is a physical system - i.e. $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are actual real-world data.

I know that you can't solve the system by inverting $\mathbf{BB'}$ because it's not full rank. My question is: is there some "clever" way to solve for $\mathbf{X}$? For example, using the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse? I made a numerical example in MATLAB, and found out that

$\mathbf{X}=(\mathbf{BB}')^{+}\mathbf{BAB'}\left[(\mathbf{BB}')^{+}\right]'$

where $(\mathbf{BB}')^{+}$ is the pseudoinverse of $\mathbf{BB}'$

either solves or approximately solves the problem. Except, I don't know what the hell I'm doing when I solve the system in this way. How do interpret the resulting $\mathbf{X}$? Are there other ways to solve the problem? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation in the OP posting is a particular case of the general equation
$$\begin{align}AXB=C\tag{0}\label{zero}\end{align}$$
Where $A, B, C$ are known matrices, $X$ is unknown, and all compatible with respect to matrix multiplication. Here I present first a simple analysis of these types of equations and then focus on the OP's.

The following result summarizes what it is known about \eqref{zero}

> **Lemma:** Given $A\in\operatorname{mat}_\mathbb{C}(m,n)$ and $B\in\operatorname{mat}_\mathbb{C}(p,q)$, and $C\in\operatorname{mat}_\mathbb{C}(m,q)$. The equation
> $$\begin{align}AXB=C\end{align}\tag{1}\label{one}$$ has a solution iff
> $$\begin{align}AA^+CB^+B=C\tag{2}\label{two}\end{align}$$
> (here $A^+$ and $B^+$ are the Moore Penrose pseudoinverses of $A$ and $B$ respectively). In either case, all solutions to \eqref{one} are of the form
> $$X=A^+CB^+ +Y-A^+AYBB^+$$
> for arbitrary (yet dimension compatible) matrix $Y$.

---

*Proof of Lemma:*
Suppose (1) has a solution $X$. Then
$$AA^+CB^+B=AA^+(AXB)B^+B=(AA^+A)X(BB^+B)=AXB=C$$

Conversely, if (2) holds, then $X=A^+CB^+$ solves \eqref{one}.

For the last statement, notice that for any $Y\in\operatorname{mat}_{\mathbb{C}}(n, p)$,
$A(Y-A^+AYBB^+)B=0$.

---

In the context of the OP, the equation
\begin{align}
B^*XB=A\tag{3}\label{three}
\end{align}
has solution iff
$$B^*(B^*)^+AB^+B=A$$
It is easy to check that for any matrix $B$,
$(B^*)^+=(B^+)^*$. Also, using some properties of the orthogonal projections, it can be shown that
$$B^+=(B^*B)^+B^*$$
Hence, any matrix of the form
\begin{align}
X &= (B^*)^+AB^+ + Y- (B^*)^+B^*YBB^+\\
&=(BB^*)^+BA(B^*B)^+B^*+ Y-(B^*)^+B^*YBB^+,
\end{align}
where $Y$ is an arbitrary matrix compatible with the product, is a solution to \eqref{three}. The choice $Y=0_{n\times p}$ corresponds to the "apparent" solution that the OP posted.

---

***A few comments about the MP-invrse:*** Recall that $A^+$ is the matrix that satisfies

1. $AXA=A$
2. $XAX=X$
3. $(AX)^*=AX$
4. $(XA)^*=XA$

where for any matrix, $M^*$ is the transpose complex conjugate of $M$.

$A^+$ exists and is unique. Furthermore, $A^+$ satisfies
$$A^+=(A^*A)^+A^*$$
This last property is related to the problem of least square errors: Given $A\in\operatorname{mat}_\mathbb{C}(m,n)$ and $b\in\mathbb{C}^m$, find $\beta \in \mathbb{C}^n$ such that

$$\beta=\operatorname{arg}\min\{\|x\|_2: \|Ax-b\|_2=\min\{\|Ay-b\|_2:y\in\mathbb{C}^n\}\}$$
This problem has solution $\beta=A^+b$